# Changing a pending intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I use a `notificationListenerService` to get the push notifications of a specific app and then to get the notifications `PendingIntent` and show a dialog with a few pieces of information.

**Is there any way to get only the intent? Or the Intent extras? Or for instance, is there any to change the flags of that pending intent?**

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: see `PendingIntent#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: I've understood (perhaps incorrectly) that the PendingIntent#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT replaces old PendingIntent's with the new one. I'm trying to keep the old ones but change the flag of the new PendingIntent (from #FLAG_ONE_SHOT to a regular PendingIntent that can be used more than once)

Comment: it replaces the "extras", not PendingIntent

Comment: @pskink My problem is I'm getting the 'PendingIntent' from an external app so I can't initialize it... But it is set up with a '#FLAG_ONE_SHOT'. Is there a way to make it work more than one shot?

Comment: what would be use of `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` then?

Comment: @pskink so it's impossible to change that?

Comment: if the creator set `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` you cannot help it

Comment: :( is there any way to get only the intent's extras or something of the sort?

Comment: @pskink oh well.. Thank you any way!

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept the answer so this question doesn't show up on the list of unanswered questions.